# How do I list all parent directories of the current directory in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to list all the parent directories of the current directory.

For example:

```
C:\a\b\c\d\e>list-all-parent-directories.bat
C:\a\b\c\d
C:\a\b\c
C:\a\b
C:\a
C:
```

Comment: The last one should read `C:\ `...

Comment: I think you forgot the `C:\a\b` directory?

Answer (score 3):

You can try a recursive approach

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
:echoParent
    for %%a in ("%~f1.") do if not "%%~fa"=="%%~dpa" (
        for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do echo %%~fb
        call :echoParent "%%~dpa"
    )
```

It will just call itself for each of the parent folders until the full path of the current folder matches its drive and path (on root current folder and parent folder are the same folder)

Or you can try with a classic `cd / echo` approach

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
:echoParent
    cd .. & if not "!cd!"=="%cd%" ( echo !cd! & goto :echoParent )
```

In this case the "trick" is that the `%cd%` variable is resolved at parse time, before the `cd ..` has been executed, but `!cd!` is resolved at execution time, after the `cd ..` has been executed. Both variables will only match at root folder. If they don't match, the current active directory is echoed to console.

All the `cd ..` changes are discarded when the batch file ends and `setlocal` is reverted, keeping the original active directory.

Answer (score 3):

Next script works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
call :showParent "%CD%"
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:showParent
  set "_Parent=%~dp1"
  echo(%_Parent:~0,-1%
  if NOT "%~dp1"=="%~d1\" call :showParent "%_Parent:~0,-1%"
goto :eof
```

Sample output:

```
D:\bat\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722> D:\bat\SO\41308193.bat
D:\bat\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp
D:\bat\Users\Sev\AppData\Local
D:\bat\Users\Sev\AppData
D:\bat\Users\Sev
D:\bat\Users
D:\bat
D:

D:\bat\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
Call :DirUp "%CD%"&Goto :Eof
:DirUp
Set "ThisDir=%~dp1"&Echo:%~dp1
if Not ":\" Equ "%ThisDir:~-2%" Call :DirUp "%~dp1."
```

Without terminating backslash

@Echo off

```
Call :DirUp "%CD%"&Goto :Eof
:DirUp
Set "ThisDir=%~dp1"
Echo:%ThisDir:~0,-1%
if Not ":\" Equ "%ThisDir:~-2%" Call :DirUp "%ThisDir:~0,-1%"
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a non-recursive approach is simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "this=" & set "next="
for %%a in ("%cd:\=" "%") do (
   set "this=!this!\!next!"
   set "next=%%~a"
   if "!this:~2!" neq "" echo !this:~2!
)
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it fails if the current directory path includes any `!` character.